# Keyboard squashing scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm struggling a bit with ScrollView and xml.

When I have the keyboard down, my screen looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4M0k.jpg

However, when I have the keyboard up, my screen looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDr6M.jpg

How do I stop the button from overlapping the last 2 EditTexts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in the Manifest.xml you need to specify 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|Keyboard"

Comment: The second "keyboard" should start with a lower case k instead of an upper case K.

Comment: What layout are you using? Sometimes you face this issue in a List or Linear layout.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and using relative layout and declaring the orientation change in manifest got me out of the situation.